# ASP.NET MVC3 how to switch the validation to different JS validation framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How to switch the validation to different JS validation framework in ASP.NET MVC3? The default is Jquery validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find more details for what you want to do?
[link text](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html)

You can also read this other question here: [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410025/client-side-model-level-or-form-level-validation-with-asp-net-mvc3)